# ComputedProperty on a component only updates the first time the watched property is set to a given value (when the property is a model property)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I seem to be having a bit of an issue with computed properties on ember 1.7.0 inside of a component. Let's say I have 2 models, A & B. A has a "belongsTo" relationships to B.

On my component template I have an Ember.Select control which will allow one to select a B entry for A.

```
{{view Ember.Select class="form-control" content=bList selection=objectA.objectB optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

In my component I have a computed property which watches for changes on `objectA.objectB` like so:

```
isSomething: function() {
    return this.get("objectA.objectB.id") === "some id";
}.property("objectA.objectB"),
```

Then in my component template I conditionally display something based on the value of `isSomething`:

```
{{#if isSomething}}
    Something :D
{{/if}}
```

If I place a breakpoint in the `isSomething` computed property, and I select a new value on the select control, it hits the breakpoint as expected. It will hit again after I select a new value. But if I then select the original value again, the breakpoint will not hit (and the component will not rerender). It seems to only be hitting the first time I select any given value in the select control. At first I thought this may be an issue with caching, but adding `volatile()` to the property didn't seem to make a difference.

I can get around this by binding the select control selection to a property on the component like `tempObjectB`, and changing the property being monitored by `isSomething` to `tempObjectB` as follows:

```
isSomething: function() {
    return this.get("tempObjectB") === "some id";
}.property("tempObjectB"),
```

Then to keep `objectA`'s reference updated I can use a method which observes all changes to `tempObjectB` and updates `objectA.objectB` as follows:

```
updateObjectA: function() {
    this.set("objectA.objectB", this.get("tempObjectB"));
}.observes("tempObjectB"),
```

These changes will allow the breakpoint to be hit every single time I change the value in the select control.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behaviour? I'd rather not resort to creating a temporary variable.

1. http://jsbin.com/qeyite/1/edit?html,js,output
2. http://jsbin.com/kugino/3/edit?html,js,output

The only difference between the two is that the first bin is storing and watching on `objectA.objectB`, while the second bin is storing and watching on `tempObjectB`.

Comment: Would you mind creating a jsbin showing the issue.  Here are some great templates for starting: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info

Comment: Doh... Should have done that with the original post... Will update soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles accross this, it appears to be fixed as of latest Ember.js release (1.8.1).

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5578